# jieba.analyse: 'generator' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python

I have to encode that json file by utf-8 and use a generator to get content. when I tried to run it, there is an `AttributeError`:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Files\python\yiyouhome\WordSeg\json_load.py", line 25, in <module>
    tags = jieba.analyse.extract_tags(content_seg,topK = top_K, withWeight = False, allowPOS = allow_pos)
  File "C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jieba\analyse\tfidf.py", line 94, in extract_tags
    for w in words:
  File "C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jieba\posseg\__init__.py", line 249, in cut
    for w in self.__cut_internal(sentence, HMM=HMM):
  File "C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jieba\posseg\__init__.py", line 217, in __cut_internal
    sentence = strdecode(sentence)
  File "C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jieba\_compat.py", line 37, in strdecode
    sentence = sentence.decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Why does this happen?

At first:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Files\python\yiyouhome\WordSeg\json_load.py", line 10, in <module>
    json_data = open('spider_raw.json',encoding = 'gbk').read() #,encoding = 'utf-8'
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 74: illegal multibyte sequence
```

So i add encoding = 'utf-8' to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
import json

import jieba.analyse

import jieba.posseg as pseg

json_data = open('spider_raw.json',encoding = 'utf-8').read()

data = json.loads(json_data)

top_K = 20

allow_pos = ('nr',)
def getcontent(spiderlist):
   for k,v in spiderlist.items():
      for item in v['talk_mutidetails']:
         yield(item['cotent'])
#def getcontenttopic(spiderlist):

item = getcontent(data)
content_seg = pseg.cut(item)
tags = jieba.analyse.extract_tags(content_seg,topK = top_K, withWeight = False, allowPOS = allow_pos)

for t in tags:
   print(t)
```

Comment: You should add the entire traceback, the failure is not in the code you're showing.

Comment: entire traceback updated, thx for helping. my json file'format is gbk.

Comment: Looks like a bug in `jieba`.

Comment: is there a way to skip or fix it ?

Comment: Could be that the bug is triggered by the supplied input. Check if your `getcontent()` really does what you expect. I see potential typos in there: `talk_mutidetails` vs `talk_multidetails` or `cotent` vs `content`. Check against the actual `spiderlist` data it gets.

Comment: .....my json file have the same spelling error, so getcontent() can get the right content. Then i also can cut sentence exactly. There must be something wrong with jieba.analyse.extract_tags. Do i need to change the format of this input( jieba.analyse.extract_tags(sentence))